# How to loadGraphModel in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I am building an Chrome Extension using a tfjs model. I have a file containing the model(model.json) and its weight. May I know how can I load it into my Chrome Extension, as I only able to load in a normal javascript file using `tf.loadGraphModel`.

Answer (score 0):

its exactly the same in extension, so i'd suggest to revisit how extensions are structured.